# Prevent users to access some routes in Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm using building an SPA using Laravel and Vue and I don't want users to access the `/products/create` route I've tried using Laravel middlewares but it didn't help

Here's my App.vue component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Navbar :name="user.name"/>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Navbar from "./Navbar";
    export default {
        name: "App",

        props: [
            'user'
        ],

        components: {
            Navbar,
        },

        created() {
            window.axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
                config.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.user.api_token;
                return config;
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

IsAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! Auth::user()->isAdmin) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

How do I redirect non-authorized users to a 404 page?

Comment: how do you do it in laravel ? Are you using roles in every user ?

Comment: *"I've tried using Laravel middlewares but it didn't help"* - I don't see any middleware code in your question... If you've tried it and it didn't work, include that code so we can see what went wrong with your approach.

Comment: Please share your code :) (middlewares)

Comment: Thanks. I've shared it.

Answer (score 6):

## For vue routes protection

To protect vue routes you can use navigation guards which are a specific feature within Vue Router that provide additional functionality pertaining to how routes get resolved.

**You must be using vue-router package to use routes in vuejs app**

In `src/router/index.js` , you can add route guard as following

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Main from "@/components/Main";
import Products from "@/components/Products";
import Create from "@/components/Create";
import Show from "@/components/Show";
import Unauthorised from "@/components/Unauthorised";

//use vue router 
Vue.use(Router);

//init Router and define some routes
export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Main',
            component: Main
        },
        {
            path: '/products',
            name: 'Products',
            component: Products
        },
        {
            path: '/create',
            name: 'Create',
            component: Create
        },
        {
            path: '/show',
            name: 'Show',
            component: Show
        },
        {
            path: '/unauthorised',
            name: 'Unauthorised',
            component: Unauthorised
        }

    ]
})

//apply route guard  
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
//list of blocked routes
    const protectedRoutes = ['/products', '/create'];
//the route user is trying to access is in blocked routes list
    if (protectedRoutes.includes(to.path)) {
//redirect to route having unauhorised message page
        return next('/unauthorised');
    }
)
else
{
// otherwise allow user to access route
    return next();
}
```

**In this example there are five routes i.e `/` , `/products` , `/create` , `/show` and last one `/unauthorised` to show error. Here, if any user tries to access routes listed in `$protectedRoutes` then they will be redirected to `/unauthorised` route otherwise allowed to access other routes**

*you can learn more about vue router guard [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) and about `vue-router` [here](https://codingthesmartway.com/vue-js-routing-with-vue-router/).Additionally, you can guard your routes based on user roles or any other conditions.I recommend you to use `vuex` to manage user state and manage routes access based on role stored on user state*

Answer (score 4):

You're not providing enough information, but the way I do it is using [Laravel policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#writing-policies).

I would setup a policy for Products like this:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Product;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ProductPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create products.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('create products');
    }
}
```

Register your policies in the App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Product' => 'App\Policies\ProductPolicy',
    ];
```

Then in your Product controller you will need to add this in order to got through the authorization process:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Product::class)
        // The current user is authorized to make this request.
    }
}
```

You will probably like to prevent unauthorized users to even have access your vue route where you create products. In order to do so you would have to pass the users permissions into your vue app.

```
return [
    'name' => $user->name,
    'permissions' => [
        'createProducts' => $user->can('create', \App\Product::class)
    ]
}
```

Then in your vue app:

```
<router-link v-if="user.permissions.createProducts" to="/products/create">
    New Product
</router-link>
```

Comment: But how can I redirect the non-authorized users to a 404 page? I have a role column in my users table.

Comment: I see you edited your question, If you are using your middleware with a vue spa and axios. You can simply catch tan error response and then redirect the user to an unahtoized route in your vue router.
`axios.post('/products', this.product).then(response => {
//success
}).catch(error => {
if(error.response.status == 403){
//redirect to unauthenticated route.
}
});`

Comment: But I don't even want users to access the create product page so when someone tries to access that route directly I want them to get an 404 page

Comment: Since you are building an spa with a laravel backend a middleware on laravel's side wont help you when changing routes, because all route changes will be handled by  the vue router, so you would have to implement something like kamal's answer below, but before you will need to pass down your user's permissions into your vue application, in that case I would recommend using vuex to store the user and his permissions.